# Mysites like page that lists all doc libraries across all SharePoint sites?

Tags: sharepoint, search, doc

We'd like to create a web page that will list all Document libraries across all sharePoint Sites for the user currently accessing the page. We'd also like to offer a all site search for the user. That is all sites they have access to.

We currently do not have Mysites enabled, nor do we want to.

Possilbe to code this?

Comment: Also, by chance anybody got SQL MSforeachdb , CAML, LINQ or SP Object Model code that produces a list of URLs to every Document Library a user has access to across all sites on the Farm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All site search is easy.  If you are using the non-free version of SharePoint 2007 or 2010, then that capability is baked into the product.  Users can use the search scopes to search across all content in the SharePoint farm.  It will automatically trim search results that users don't have access to.

As for you list of all document libraries, this would probably be too much effort to generate in real time for any non-trivial SharePoint environment.  You are most likely going to have to gather this information ahead of time and then display the appropriate summary of the data in a WebPart of some other similar interface.  Code to crawl every web application and every site and every sub-site and then every Document Library isn't hard.  Actually it is very straightforward.  What will be a little tricky is that you will need to collect ACL entries for each of these lists so that you can compare them to the current end user.  The real trick is that the ACLs might contain SharePoint Group names and Active Directory group names instead of individual end user names.  That will make your reporting task more difficult.

Comment: So we can a search scope in a specific site collection that reports findings at the farm level? I think you are right about building the list of doc libraries to maybe every night after indexing runs. Would you do this in SP object model? tempted to do it in SQL since I'd like to store in it in a SQL table anyways. By chance got know where of any guides that might get me started on these?

Comment: I wouldn't attempt it via direct database calls. The database schema isn't documented, it is convoluted and you are violating your support contract.  The object model code is straightforward and it will be very performant for your needs.